# From where application.properties file gets loaded?

Tags: java, spring

I'm not sure how to place this question but am struggling to find this from last couple of days. So please share any possible suggestions to unlock my doubt.

I've one already written code where they are using log4j for logging. So while checking that, from where they are accessing the `log4j.properties` file to access properties in code to create logs. I found that is coming from application.properties file.

Here the problem starts.

There is one Log4jloader class is there like below

```
    class  Log4jloader {

    private String log4jConfig

    public void setLog4jCOnfig(String log4jConfig){

        this.log4jConfig = log4jConfig;
        setlog4jProperty(log4jConfig);

    }
}
```

Later I've found that log4j.properties file's path location is coming from `${common.log4j.properties}` in below xml.

```
<bean id = "Log4jloader" class = "pop.hpt.Log4jloader">
   <property name = "log4jConfig" value = "${common.log4j.properties}"/>
</bean>
```

And value of this variable `${common.log4j.properties}` is coming from application.properties file. And also have searched where this file is placed, but not able to find how THIS `application.prioperties` file is getting loaded int code.

Can anyone please help me how this file gets loaded in code...? Looking this from last almost one week..!I'm only aware of that is spring is came into a picture and this is something default functionality of Spring framework. (Am I WRONG ? )

Comment: application.properties is common for spring-boot applications. Is your application a pure Spring application or is it SpringBoot application?

Comment: @hovanessyan, Core Java + Spring application..!